# How to extend the select2 component drop-down beyond the jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using the [select2](https://select2.github.io) component in a jquery modal dialog. I need the drop-down to display beyond the border of the dialog. Right now a long drop-down is truncated by the dialog border.

Here's an example and the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhL6oh6y/1/):

```
<div id="test-dialog" class="widget" style="display:none;">
    <form id="Newfrm" name="Newfrm" method="post">
        <fieldset id="Field" step="1" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <label for="NewField" style="width:90px; text-align:right;">Field</label>
            <select name="NewField" id="NewField">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">test1</option>
                <option value="2">test2</option>
                <option value="3">test3</option>
                <option value="4">test4</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

$("#NewField").select2({
            placeholder: "Select a Field",
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownParent: $('#test-dialog')
        });

$("#test-dialog").dialog({
            width: "550",
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        }).dialog('option', 'title', 'New Test Dlg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change

```
<div id="test-dialog" class="widget" style="display:none;">
```

to

```
<div id="test-dialog" class="widget" style="display:none; overflow:visible !important">
```